# How to achieve duplex communication? (listen/talk simultaneously)

Tags: ros, talker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For example, if I want my machine1 to send its updated status to machine2, and I also want my machine2 to also do the thing in the reverse direction. How should I do that?

constraint:

- Both machines are executing some missions (e.g. path following), so it is not a duplex messaging project.

Please show me a little more detail on whatever package/method you recommend because I am  a beginner on ROS (I have read almost all ROS beginner's tutorials), and my deadline is approaching.

Truly thankful.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69415/how-to-achieve-duplex-communication?-(listen/talk-simultaneously)/) by [Bholms](https://answers.ros.org/users/5097/bholms/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2013-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have a reliable connection you could set the ros master on one of the machines, and then have a topic published by each machine that contain whatever data you want to send.

Each machine publishes it's own topic and subscribes to the other machine's topic.

Overview for python:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers

Overview for c++:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers

You can find many examples in the tutorial section.

---

Originally posted by [Victor Lopez](https://answers.ros.org/users/395/victor-lopez/) with karma: 651 on 2013-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1